# VBA - Count Non Blank Cells Using Cell Reference

Tags: vba, excel

In VBA, using Excel 2016, I am trying to count the number of non-blank cells for a given range but using only the cell integer reference. I've tried the following:

```
WB.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(2, X), _
Cells(2, Y)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
```

Where X and Y are cell references for the columns. Please assist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Range(WB.Sheets(1).Cells(2, X), _
WB.Sheets(1).Cells(2, Y)).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count
```

You should add the workbook and worksheet before the cell and not before the range

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using the excel formula `CountA` as you're probably aware.

You can also use this in VBA using:

```
with WB.sheets(1)
    WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(.Cells(2, X), .Cells(2, Y)))
end with
```

Comment: Way faster than SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).count if you use it on big sheets with scattered data.

Answer (score 1):

try in this way:

```
Dim nonBlanck as long
    nonBlanck = WorksheetFunction.CountA(WB.Sheets(1). _
              Range(Cells(2, X), Cells(2, Y)). _   
                         SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
```

However, if `WB.SHeets(1)` is not active then you could have some problems. Therefore try with this improved solution:

```
Dim nonBlanck as long
    With  WB.Sheets(1)
        nonBlanck = WorksheetFunction.CountA( _
              .Range(.Cells(2, X), .Cells(2, Y)). _   
                         SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants))
    End With
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a way to define the range of **clipped columns** and then apply `SpecialCells`:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, rng As Range

    x = 3
    y = 5
    Set rng = Range(Cells(2, x), Cells(Rows.Count, y))
    MsgBox rng.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Count
End Sub
```

[image]